# What is the meaning of temporal part?

Tags: waves, spacetime, differential-equations

We know that the solution to the classical wave equation, $u(x,t)$ can be expressed as a product of two functions of $x$ and $t$, namely

$$u(x,t)= X(x)T(t)$$

I was wondering why is $X(x)$ called the spatial part and $T(t)$ called the temporal part of the wave function? Can someone provide me a logical insight?

Comment: Do you have any questions or need clarification?

Comment: The spatial part is only dependent on position and independent of time. The temporal means having to do with time and note it does not depend on position having only dependence on $t$.

Answer (score 1):

For $X(x)$:

If you set $t$ to be a constant $t0$, then $X(x)$ will be a picture of the wave as a function of $x$, frozen at time $t = t_0$. (think of a storage scope triggered at time $t_0$)

For $T(t)$:

If you set $x$ to be a constant $x_0$, then $T(t)$ will show how the wave varies with time at the point $x = x_0$. (think of an oscilloscope with a probe connected to $x_0$)